# How do i demonstrate the power of Docker?

Tags: docker

I have basic Docker knowledge and I want to convince someone of the potential Docker has to improve all kind of processes. How can I demonstrate the power of docker, instead of only telling them the theory behind it?

Comment: Deploy something with dependencies that would normally take 4 hours of installation and configuration

Comment: I am curious about this too.  I am to demonstrate it's use for Cordova.  So setting up gradle, environment variables, java, git, android studio, xcode, cordova itself, node, all with a single command on a mac or windows is very appealing.

Comment: @OlegSklyar Yeah that was what I was thinking, but I am looking for idea's :)

Comment: I would go for something simple and visual, take e.g. `wekan` and deploy it in one line. Even better would be a docker compose file for something like wekan plus the DB plus the remote proxy with e.g. caddy running with Let'sEncrypt automatic TLS provisioning